# sweet.js replace this. with @

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I want to replace `this.` with `@` sign like in coffee script. I've write the macro:

```
macro (@) {
    case { return $a } => { return this.$a }
}

function LogSmth(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log(@name);
}
```

But got

```
SyntaxError: [macro] Macro `@` could not be matched with `name...`
57:     console.log(@name);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to expand on Mike C's answer. What happens if we try and do something just with `@` (a common operation is to bind an object to `this`). One might write: `X.bind(@, ...)` but this would fail with the above macro. Another possibility is the ability to do this: `@['some property with a weird name']`, but this would also fail with the above macro.

Here's my version:

```
macro @ {
  rule { [$x:expr] } => { this[$x] }
  rule { $x:ident } => { this.$x }
  rule {} => { this }
}
```

This also exposes one useful property about applying rules to macros which is that order matters.

Comment: Thanks. I made this one an answer for the future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

Cases have to return a syntax array. So you could fix yours by doing the following:

```
macro @ {
    case { _ } => { return #{ this. } }
}
```

Or you could produce this using a simple [rule](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#rule-macros) that doesn't use any patterns.

```
macro @ {
    rule {
    } => {
        this.
    }
}
```